# ImportError: cannot import name celery from app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery

Am a newbie in python and celery, and am having import issues, below is my project structure :

```
project/
    app/
       starwars/
          star_wars.py
       utils/
           flask_Celery.py
           tasks.py
       __init__.py
```

This is what my `__init__.py` file has :

```
from app.starwars.star_wars import StarWars
from app.utils.flask_celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)


# configure celery
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://redis:6379/0',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://redis:6379/0'
)
celery = make_celery(app)

# secret key
app.secret_key = "xxxxxx"
api = Api(app)

# Cross Origin Resource Sharing
CORS(app)


api.add_resource(StarWars, '/api/v1/starwars')
```

Then when I access it inside `star_wars.py` that's where I get the import error, what am I missing? below is my code :

```
from ..utils.tasks import paginate_requested_data


class StarWars(Resource):

    def get(self):
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
        res = paginate_requested_data.delay()
        return {'hello': '{}'.format(res)}
```

`Tasks.py` , this is the code below :

```
from celery.worker.state import requests

from app import celery

@celery.task(name='starwars_paginate')
def paginate_requested_data():
    results = []
    pagination = 1
    url = 'https://swapi.co/api/starships/'
    params = {'page': pagination}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)

    data = r.json()

    for i in data['results']:
        dict_res = {'name': i['name'], 'hyperdrive_rating': i['hyperdrive_rating']}
        results.append(dict_res)

    while r.status_code == 200:
        try:
            pagination += 1
            params['page'] = pagination
            r = requests.get(url, params=params)
            data = r.json()
            for i in data['results']:
                dict_res = {'name': i['name'], 'hyperdrive_rating': i['hyperdrive_rating']}
                results.append(dict_res)
        except KeyError:
            print('stop')

    return results


@celery.task(name='starwars_test')
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This the error am getting :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Huxy/PycharmProjects/starwars_challenge/app.py", line 1, in
> <module>
>     from app import *   File "C:\Users\Huxy\PycharmProjects\starwars_challenge\app\__init__.py",
> line 7, in <module>
>     from app.starwars.star_wars import StarWars   File "C:\Users\Huxy\PycharmProjects\starwars_challenge\app\starwars\star_wars.py",
> line 8, in <module>
>     from ..utils.tasks import paginate_requested_data   File "C:\Users\Huxy\PycharmProjects\starwars_challenge\app\utils\tasks.py",
> line 3, in <module>
>     from app import celery ImportError: cannot import name 'celery' from 'app'
> (C:\Users\Huxy\PycharmProjects\starwars_challenge\app\__init__.py)
```

Comment: `File "C:\Users\Huxy\PycharmProjects\starwars_challenge\app\utils\tasks.py", line 3, in from app import celery` is pretty clear: you import `celery` which should be inside `app`. But neither `celery.py` nor `tasks.py` is listed in your question. Your question details appear to be incomplete.

Comment: For tracebacks, it's better to use code blocks for formatting: it makes them a lot more readable.

Comment: The celery am using here is not `celery.py`, it's a variable in the `__init__.py`  , which is this `celery = make_celery(app)`

Comment: @00, I have added `tasks.py`  in the question, kindly check it out

Comment: Be aware that you seem to have both an `app.py` and an `app/__init__.py`; presumably, your import order (`PYTHONPATH`) is set so the former takes priority for import statements.

Comment: @00, `from app import celery` is `tasks.py`, sorry I have included it there